# How to conduct the training of NER models for 'Urdu' in OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I would like to train a NER models using Apache OpenNLP for my native language Urdu. I have training data in `train.txt` ready. 
What are the next steps to make a trained model(.bin), like we find on [OpenNLP site](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) in the model download section.

Comment: See http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training

Answer (score 3):

```
opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -model model.bin -lang en -data train.txt -encoding UTF-8
```

using this command, you can create your model.bin

please refer to the documentation for extra information!

Comment: on the contrary, we can use api's as well which are given in the documentation.